# What is the difference between "moocher" and "smoocher"?

Tags: differences

I live in France, so I lack vocabulary.

I heard the word *moocher* in the debate between O'Reilly and Stewart. I wanted to know the difference to *smoocher*.

Comment: I doubt that living in France causes you to lack vocabulary. You only lack *English* vocabulary. Talk to *L'Académie française* to rectify that situation.

Comment: Please check a dictionary first, for example: http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moocher http://www.thefreedictionary.com/smoocher

Comment: Jokoon, like Hugo said: when you have a question like this, about the meanings of words, your first reaction should be to look in the place that words are defined, namely a dictionary. Once you've done that, if you're still puzzled, go ahead an ask your question, but *show your work*: tell us what you found in the dictionary, and why that isn't sufficient to resolve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Well, they are really completely different words with completely different meanings.

To "mooch" is to beg or borrow what you need from someone else rather than acquiring and using your own.

A "smooch" is a kiss.

I don't think they are related, and the fact that they are only one letter apart is just a coincidence.

Comment: They have about as much relation as "lose" and "close", or "rag" and "crag", or "Java" and "Javascript".

Comment: @Jay: Or "jay" and "Jay" and *j'ai*.